# RFID to Raspberry pins

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, i2c, sensor, rfid

I am working on a school project and need to connect Rfid RC522 and tuchscreen to raspberry, problem is that tuchscreen is using same GPIO pins as Rfid, I Got suggested connect RFID using I2c And use only 4 pins, any other tips or how to execute suggested tip.

Comment: What display?  Which GPIO is it using?  Which GPIO are needed by the RFID?  See https://pinout.xyz/  Edit your question to include details.

Comment: You can have multiuple devices on a single SPI interface, that's what the CS pin is for - having said that, I've found the RC522 works better over I2C anyway

Comment: @joan its waveshare 7" tuchscreen  its using first 26 pins, , while RFID uses 1(3.3V), 6(GND), 19(MOSI), 21(MISO), 22(RST),23(SCK), 24(SDA)

Comment: @JaromandaX How to enable/connect it to I2C I cant find any usefull info...

Comment: enable i2c on the pi?

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, I now know how to ena le I2c, wich pins do I now connect RC522 with and do I need to change code in order to sensor to work? As I said I am New to raspberry pi so I am quite lost

Comment: `wich pins do I now connect RC522` - SDA and SCL ... `do I need to change code in order to sensor to work` - yes, you need to use i2c instead of spi

Comment: The following Q&A might help: Can RFID read stacked cards? Asked 8 months ago Active 8 months ago Viewed 250 times 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519993/can-rfid-read-stacked-cards/520007#520007